# Ruby: Metaprogramming in conditional sentence

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a **very repetitive conditional sentence**. I was wondering if can be cleaned up with a bit of *metaprogramming*.

This is a simplified example of what I'm dealing with:

```
FILTERS = [
  :filter1,
  :filter2,
  :filter3
]

def filter1; true; end
def filter2; true; end
def filter3; true; end

if(
  send( FILTERS[0] ) &&
  send( FILTERS[1] ) &&
  send( FILTERS[2] )
)
  puts "DONE!"
end
```

(In my real case the `FILTERS` array contains 27 elements)

The target is to **replace the three lines** into the `if` sentence with some kind of *automatic* iteration through **all the filter methods**.

Another important match is to keep the *fast out* behavior of the `&&` command: in case `filter1` is `false` neither `filter2` or `filter3` will be executed.

The `FILTERS` array is just there to help in finding the *elegant* solution, you don't must to use it.

Comment: if filtersX contains only a boolean value why don't you store it in a hash , FILTERS = { filter1: true , filter2: true , filter3: false } and itterate over the hash ?

Comment: shouldn't the filters return something? (so one filter acts on the output of the previous one). Or do they work by doing side-effects? (like Rails' `before_filters`)

Comment: @lesce the filter methods implementations shown here are _simplified_ examples. The real ones are more complex. Any how the real problem is how to iterate over the results keeping the `&&` behavior.. as @Tass has resolved.

Comment: @tokland the filters should work independently not coupling between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
FILTERS.all? {|filter| send(filter) } and puts "DONE!"
```